# Refresh UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with refreshing my custom UITableView inside an UIViewController.

When appear the tableView has all its cell with a clear backgroundcolor.
I have a "start" button above and when I click on it I want to have all the cell in another color.

I have specified the rules in:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if self.status == "start" {

        if indexPath != self.currentIndexPath {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0  , green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }

    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}
```

In the "start" action button, I call: `self.tableView.reloadData`

```
@IBAction func startAction(sender: AnyObject) {
self.currentIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

self.status = "start"
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But it's not working very well as I must scroll to update the background color.

I tried to use the `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method. But the result is the same.

I always must scroll the tableView to update the background color or some images.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: did you got self.currentIndexPath ? as I cannot see any code related to self.currentIndexPath in func startAction(sender: AnyObject)

Comment: I just forget to quote it here but its well defined in my code. I updated the code above with the currentIndexPath

Comment: please check have you assign tableView IBOutlet or not.

Comment: @jay: yes of course.

Answer (score 15):

Replace your call to reloadData with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. UI updates should be run on `DispatchQueue.main`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably put your logic inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, this will get called when you reload the table.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath)
    if self.status == "start" {
        if indexPath != self.currentIndexPath {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0  , green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

As I can't see your current implementation of this method I have just guessed at your dequeuing of the cell, you may need to change this slightly, If you can post this code in your question I can help.

Comment: I also try to did it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath as you said. But I always must scroll after clicking on "start" to update the background color

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your codes on  WillDisplayCell add in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
@IBAction func startAction(sender: UIButton)
{

    let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableview )

    self.currentIndexPath  = self.tableview.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!
    self.status = "start"
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer to the question about refreshing the tableview

Comment: still not working. I put the color rules in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" but it s not working: I must scroll the tableView to update the cells

Answer (score 0):

You've got the logic in the wrong place. `willDisplayCell` is called just before the cell is drawn which is why it makes sense that you're seeing the change when you scroll. Calling `reloadData` is going to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so you should move your logic to that method.

Comment: I already did it in cellForRowAtIndexPath but I must scroll to update the cells.